# Google TPU: when/how will it be available to me?

Tags: deep-learning, google

Google recently [announced the TPU custom chip](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/05/Google-supercharges-machine-learning-tasks-with-custom-chip.html).

They stated it is available in Google Cloud Platform, but only for their internal usage.

When will I be able to use it? Will it be possible to buy this chip or will it be only accessible through their cloud?

Comment: Welcome to DS.SE. Your question seems to be focused at the TPU custom chip, rather than a data science question as such. Im wondering if this would be better asked in a hardware/cloud SE? (A qn for the mods?)

Comment: Hi, @MarcusD. You have a good point. When I chose to post in DS.SE, it was because here are the users intended to use this new technology. But both communities seem good places to post this question.

Comment: It is a fair point. the DS community cuts across a number of communities (including hardware, systems, data sources, analytics, visualisation) which is why it exists ...

Answer (score 4):

Google has apparently said it would not be available for sale outside of Google.

http://www.forbes.com/sites/tiriasresearch/2016/05/26/google-builds-its-first-chip-just-for-machine-learning/#58ab2bcb7a92

Google also did mention it would be available to developers for Tensorflow and Cloud machine learning but otherwise it has been light on details or when this will become available.

Comment: Thanks @vigos. I'm trying to reach friends at Google to find out more.